# strcat with char from array in c

Tags: c, arrays, char, strcat

This may be a silly question, but I'm struggling to solve this problem.
I know that to append a char to a string I can do something like this:

```
char c;
char string[10] = "";
strcat(string, &c);
```

Now, this works well for char variables, but the problem is that when I try to append a char from an array:

```
char array[5];
char string[10] = "";
strcat(string, &array[0]); //&array[0] returns the entire array, not just array[0]
```

Question: How can I append a single char from an array to a string?

Comment: first snippet doesn't work correctly. Also You can use [strncat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat) for one character addition.

Comment: `strcat` requires a null-terminated string for its second argument.

Comment: The first part doesn't work either. Try this instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853834/597607

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use strncat().Here length is the number of characters you want to append to string

```
strncat(string, array, length);
```

For appending single character, use length = 1